# Django 2: where to add urlencode to correctly parse plus signs

Tags: django

I get a q variable as follows:

```
    q = self.request.GET.get('q')
```

However if the value of the parameter value passed has a + sign this is lost. How/where do I encode the URL to convert, for example, + signs to %2B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
q = urllib.parse.quote_plus(q)
```